# Severe delays in cloud SQL responses

Tags: google-cloud-sql

In the past 4-5 hours there have been 10s of simple read queries that took 40-70 seconds to return result from the cloud SQL DB. Usually they take 50ms or so. Is there some ongoing issue? I can provide DB IDs and specific times if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your Cloud SQL database located (US? Europe?)? where are you connecting from? (App Engine, external server, your local computer, etc).

If you're connecting from App Engine or Compute Engine, is your database setup to be as close as possible from your server?

Comment: DB ID is prod-ef2f:dev-ef2f in US. The machine that consumes the DB where I observe the delays is a google compute engine instance in the US zone too.

Comment: Make sure that your database instance is located as close as possible to your VM. You can do this by going to the Cloud SQL instance "Edit" page and change the Location Preference option to "Specify Compute Engine Zone" and selecting your zone.

Comment: OK will do. However in our architecture we have multiple engine machines in different zones to be more fault-tolerant, so a single zone selection is not very suitable. Also, this is a full minute of delay, it shouldn't be a "zone-level" issue, that's enough time for any signalling to travel anywhere in the world. I should point out that the system has been working for 6 months. Only today is particularly slow.

Comment: And you're seeing the issue from all your machines in different zones? are they all in the same Compute Engine region?

Comment: Currently I only have results from us-central1-a. I don't know about other zones at the moment. A quick test shows that it behaves well, but the issue is rare, may be 1 in 50 transactions will be bad, so it's not conclusive. I will update you again as I gather more info. Are there any zones or networks that are known to have such large delays?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46033/discussion-between-juan-enrique-munoz-zolotoochin-and-vladimir-ralev)

Answer (score 0):

Between 11.00PST and 11.30PST there was an issue that interrupted many Cloud SQL instances. The problem should now be resolved.

We apologize for the inconvenience and thank you for your patience and continued support. Please rest assured that system reliability is a top priority for the Google Cloud Platform, and we are making continuous improvements to make our systems better.

To be kept informed of other Google Cloud SQL issues and launches, please join google-cloud-sql-announce@googlegroups.com

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-sql-announce

(from Joe Faith in another thread)