# Cloud SQL errors

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Various errors started occurring in Google SQL. The system is saying temporary unavailable, but it's been quite a while. Looks like 1 in 10 queries now give 500/502 errors. Here is an example stacktrace http://pastebin.com/MNk06PT4

This is a follow-up from [Severe delays in cloud SQL responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338639/severe-delays-in-cloud-sql-responses). It could be the same issue. Same conditions, google cloud engine connected to a cloud SQL, no zone preference. Hope that sheds more light on the issue.

Comment: I get this error every time using PHP and CodeIgniter on GAE by reloading a page quickly. I do use the lowest MySQL instance (D0 tier). Tried D1 tier, but can reproduce this error every time.

Comment: Just tried tier D16 and can also reproduce this error every time using  PHP by quickly refreshing a page that queries a table having only 10 rows.

Comment: Create new topic with the google-cloud-sql tag. They probably won't see your comment here.

Comment: Ok I will. I saw some topics related to the same error, but no clear solution. And just checked that even without cloud sql I get this error. Created a hello world php file and it happens with that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Between 11.00PST and 11.30PST there was an issue that interrupted many Cloud SQL instances. The problem should now be resolved.

We apologize for the inconvenience and thank you for your patience and continued support. Please rest assured that system reliability is a top priority for the Google Cloud Platform, and we are making continuous improvements to make our systems better.

To be kept informed of other Google Cloud SQL issues and launches, please join google-cloud-sql-announce@googlegroups.com

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-sql-announce

Answer (score 0):

Seems all Google Cloud SQL is down, any expected recovery time?

https://cloud.google.com/console

```
Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Best regards
Sergio

Answer (score 0):

Also I noticed that you are using the deprecated JDBC driver that has much lower performance than using the MySQL wire protocol natively. See https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/external for information on connecting using the standard drivers.  That will help latency as well as consistency of performance.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error using CodeIgniter v2.1 and v3 on app engine and got this error as well.

It happens when using $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');

Then after a few random page refreshes this error pops up.

After changing the following in database.php:

'pconnect' => TRUE,

into

'pconnect' => FALSE,

This errors is gone in my application. Now both version 2.1 and 3 are working for me.

Maybe there is a similar setting in the framework or code you're using.